# [PM2][ERROR] Script not found: npm run start

Tags: windows, powershell, next.js, deployment, pm2

I have a NextJS app running on my windows machine. Here is the scripts portion of my package.json. According to the pm2 documentation I can just run

```
pm2 start "npm run start"
```

which works for me in wsl, but when I run it in powershell I get the following error:

```
[PM2][ERROR] Script not found: D:\Projects\MyProject\npm run start
```

package.json scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "start": "next start",
    "buildstyles": "tailwindcss -i ./src/styles/globals.css -o ./src/styles/output.css --watch",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "prettier": "prettier --write **/*"
  },
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Any news on your issue ?

Comment: I ended up switching to NSSM https://nssm.cc/, because it can at least turn into a service but I'm still having some trouble getting it completely working.